# FFT of a stretched vector

Tags: fourier-transform

Lets say I have a small size vector x=[a b c d]. Now I stretch this vector 3 times and I got x3=[a a a b b b c c c d d d]. What would be the relation between fft(x) and fft(x3)?

Comment: Is this a homework? There's nothing stopping you from viewing this with Octave/Matlab/etc.

Comment: No it is a project. I tried to view this on Matlab, and I compared the results I could not get a direct relation between the results for the two cases.

Comment: Consider the resulting impulse response "step by step", or maybe "extended step by extended step".

Comment: I assume you are suggesting doing this by hand. Now I am trying to do this by hand for the two cases. Hopefully, this will give some clue for me.

Comment: Well, if by hand is too much, then try `h=0.4*sinc(0.4*[-20:20])` and then see the differences between `a=[h;h](:).'` and `b=upsample(h,2)`. Try different upsample rates (3, 4, ...), different lengths, surely it will become apparent what the difference is and the connection with what I said.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you should split this into two steps

1. Up-sample by a factor of 3, i.e. x = [a 0 0 b 0 0 ...]. This results in a 3 times periodic repetition of the spectrum.
2. Convolve with a rectangular pulse of length three, i.e. h = [1 1 1]. This crates time stretched sequence you want. Convolution in time is multiplication in frequency, your three copies of the original spectrum get multiplied with a $sinc$ function.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is exactly the process of [Zero Order Hold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-order_hold).
You may have a look at the convolution term in the formula and extract what you need in the Fourier spectrum.